# cannot rename files with `[ ]` on its name?

Tags: debian, rename

I'd been trying to use the rename function in my debian, I searched here at unix.stackexchange but it seems the solution is not the same in my scenario which files contains `[]`

```
[800p]-[WOLU-H]-test1.mkv
[800p]-[WOLU-H]-test2.mkv
```

desired output is just

```
[WOLU-H]-test1.mkv
[WOLU-H]-test2.mkv
```

i tried

`rename [800p]-[WOLU-H] [WOLU-H] [800p]-*`

but it keeps saying:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"
    (Missing operator before p?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"
```

I tried other such as

`rename 's/[800p]-[WOLU-H]/[WOLU-H]/' [800p]-*`

but output also failed

```
Invalid [] range "U-H" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[800p]-[WOLU-H <-- HERE ]/ at (eval 1) line 1.
```

can somebody enlighten me with the correct process? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
rename 's/\[800p\]-\[WOLU-H\]/\[WOLU-H\]/' \[800p\]-*
```

but error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"
        (Missing operator before p?)
Backslash found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "p\"
Backslash found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "]\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
Backslash found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "]\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"
Unmatched right square bracket at (eval 1) line 1, at end of line
Unmatched right square bracket at (eval 1) line 1, at end of line
```

I also tried this:

```
rename "[800p]-[WOLU-H]" "[WOLU-H]" "[800p]-"*
```

But still error

```
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"
        (Missing operator before p?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"
```

I think the `-` with numerics are messing?

Comment: You need to escape `[` using `\ `.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[` and `]` have a special meaning in `bash` and also in regular expressions, so you have to escape them as `\[` and `\]`. Something like this should work:

```
rename 's/\[800p\]-\[WOLU-H\]/\[WOLU-H\]/' \[800p\]-*
```

---

Example:

```
$ touch [800p]-[WOLU-H]-test1.mkv [800p]-[WOLU-H]-test2.mkv
$ ls
[800p]-[WOLU-H]-test1.mkv  [800p]-[WOLU-H]-test2.mkv
$ rename 's/\[800p\]-\[WOLU-H\]/\[WOLU-H\]/' \[800p\]-*
$ ls
[WOLU-H]-test1.mkv  [WOLU-H]-test2.mkv
```

Comment: This is true, strictly though the error is a perl error message, arising from the use of [perl `rename` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html).

Comment: @mr.spuratic My answer was intended to be a bit more generic. `bash` refers to the expansion of `[800p]-*` in the shell and _regular expression_ to the `s/[800p]-[WOLU-H]/[WOLU-H]/` part. Such kind of an error would have probably been thrown by another tool, written in another language...

Comment: @FloHimself I don't know, but if my intuition is correct, the `-` is messing with the command? `Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"
        (Missing operator before p?)
Backslash found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "p\"
Backslash found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "]\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
Backslash found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "]\"
        (Missing operator before \?)`

Comment: @TheWolf I've added an example of how I've used the command.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply use quotes? So you don't need to escape those `[`.

```
rename "[800p]-[WOLU-H]" "[WOLU-H]" "[800p]-"*
```

(Note the `*` is out of the `"..."`)

**EDIT:** Comments make me notice it doesn't work. I don't understand why, because it works here:

```
$ ls -1
[800p]-[WOLU-H]-foobar.txt
[800p]-[WOLU-H]-hello.txt
[800p]-[WOLU-H]-world.txt

$ rename "[800p]-[WOLU-H]" "[WOLU-H]" "[800p]-[WOLU-H]"*

$ ls -1
[WOLU-H]-foobar.txt
[WOLU-H]-hello.txt
[WOLU-H]-world.txt

$ rename -V
rename (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)
```

I'm using CentOS 6.6, maybe that's the difference...
Anyway, sorry for the wrong answer...

Comment: I am getting this? `Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"
        (Missing operator before p?)
syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "800p"`

Comment: Because it does not work. `Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 4) line 1, near "800p"
 (Missing operator before p?)
syntax error at (user-supplied code), near "800p"`

Comment: @A.B. Oh, sorry. It was working on my box (see my update), I didn't notice the debian flag...

Comment: Should you wish to experiment, Debian's `rename` (perl "alternative") does not use anything expected like http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/ , but  instead something exceedingly ancient (from the same author, rmb) which you can extract from the source patch package here: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/perl